# How to pass object to web api?

Tags: c#, get, asp.net-web-api2

I have code below for a GET API method.

I can't send object parameter and have it consumed by API method. The API method is invoked, but parameter is always null.

**Q: How do I change my code to enable receiving of object input?**

In general, I guess I shouldn't send objects with GET requests? But I thought it would be possible?

I've tried with [FromBody] and without. I'm thinking objects shouldn't be [FromUri]?

For debugging I'm using Swagger; the example object is generated nicely, but when I send it, it arrives as null.

Same behaviour when using my client through RestSharp.

```
[SwaggerResponseExample(HttpStatusCode.OK, typeof(GetProductBasesRequestExamplesForSwagger))]
[SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, Type = typeof(string))]
public IHttpActionResult Get([FromBody]GetProductBasesRequest getProductBasesRequest)
{
    // transaction id to trace this calculation across processes.
    var transactionId = Guid.NewGuid();

    using (LogContext.PushProperty("Method", MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name))
    using (LogContext.PushProperty("TransactionId", transactionId))
    {
        try
        {
            if(getProductBasesRequest==null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(getProductBasesRequest),"Input can't be null");

            Log.Logger.Debug("ProductBase Get : {@GetProductBasesRequest}", getProductBasesRequest);

            var content = new GetProductBasesResponse
            {
                ProductBases = _productBaseRepository.Get()
            };
            return Ok(content);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.Logger.Error(e, "ProductBases.Get");
            return BadRequest(transactionId.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: GET requests don't have a body, that's a POST

Comment: https://restfulapi.net/http-methods/

Comment: And changing method name to post DOES fix it.

But my method really is a get -- wouldn't it be wrong to convert it to a POST? I was thinking that POST was reserved for creating, PUT for changing, GET for retrieving?

Comment: Get Req dose not have body ... try like this `public IHttpActionResult Get([ModelBinder(typeof(WebApiDataSourceRequestModelBinder))] 
 GetProductBasesRequest  getProductBasesRequest)`

Comment: @UmerZaman -- please re-comment as a solution and I'll accept it. It does answer my question on how to do it.
It will however complicate things, and I'll go for the rewrite-to-post option instead.
Thanks all, for quick replies!

Comment: The question has been down-voted and I don't understand why. Would the down-voter care to elaborate so I could learn from it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get Req dose not have body ... try like this

```
public IHttpActionResult Get([ModelBinder(typeof(WebApiDataSourceRequestModelBinder))] GetProductBasesRequest getProductBasesRequest)
```

or

```
public IHttpActionResult Get([FromUri] GetProductBasesRequest getProductBasesRequest)
```